Can I buy a stock without owning it?
I'm a young guy from Turkey and want to buy 10k worth of stocks without owning them. I want to give my 10 year old sister a fortune in 20 years when she exchanges the stocks, so she can have a fearless adult life, unlike me. Buying something without owning it is a freedom for me. I don't want to own the stock. I want to keep that secret info. I don't want to include with these stocks. I don't want to affect them and I want them to be untouchable in any scenarios. Maybe I will go to prison one day or lose my life or someone sues me in the future, then the government takes away my money.

What problem are you trying to solve by not owning the stock?  Technically, sure, you could create a trust with your sister as a beneficiary and have the trust own the stock.  But it is not clear whether that solves your actual problem.

What does "buying something without owning it" mean to you?

The country involved may make a difference.  please identify the country. Also how old is your sibling today, and what is the goal for the money: school, retirement, buy a house?

The problem I'm trying to solve by not owning is,maybe I will go to prison one day or I can lose my life or someone can sue me in the future then government take away my money btw I know these words are big but my budget is not big at all,my goal for now is buying 10k worth of stocks for 5 years and forgetting for my sister (and she can exchange the stocks in 2045 she is gonna be 30 years old)she is 10 years old now my goal is giving her a fearless adult life unlike me.And buying something without owning is freedom to me.Im a young guy from turkey.Thanks for the answers

In the US, your assets are not seized when you go to prison. They might be seized if it's necessary to settle debts. But you could buy the stock and then give it as a gift to your sister.

Remember to take into consideration what should happen to the money if your sister dies. Either before the payment starts, or after receiving a few payments, but not the whole. Does the money go back to you? Or to her children if she has any?

I think you need to talk to a financial advisor and/or lawyer that knows the legal details in your jurisdiction.
The normal vehicle to protect assets is to set up a trust. However, trusts are complicated and there are a lot of laws and regulations. If you are concerned around running into a conflict with your local government, you may have to set up a trust in a different country, which makes things even more complicated.
I commend you for wanting to look out for you little sister, but you will need professional help to do this. This is way too complicated for internet advice.

One of the simpler alternatives would be Private Pension System in Turkey.
It would be in your sister's name, so unaffected by any personal financial trouble you would go through. Your sister will have the opportunity of early withdrawal. Early withdrawal does have tax implications, which depending on investment period and gains can be larger or smaller than capital gain taxes would be. If she keeps the investments until official retirement age, she'll avoid taxes and also get a state matched contribution.
A potential benefit of this is that it can have a bit of a psychological threshold before resorting to withdrawing a pension fund. Thus your sister might be less likely to just spend it, and it will always be available as a emergency fund to provide stability.

In some countries, a personal pension scheme may not be accessible at all until a certain age such as 50 or 60.

@Henry According to this site since 2021, parents can enroll children under 18 to a pension fund in Turkey.

Side point: Whilst that "psychological threshold" might indeed benefit the OP's sister, we have no indication of her then being any more prone to burning the money than to holding it forever, and no reason to assume she would profit from being nudged to either side. At the age of 30, I'd rather assume (if anything) she'll be able to find a sensible balance between her long term and short term considerations.

It's beyond me why, when giving advice to strangers (no offense!), it's so common to presuppose one or another one-sidedness in them that therefore, allegedly, would need to be compensated by extrinsic incentives/deterrents - without even knowing on which side (if any) the particular person tends to err.

There are people who spend their fortune too quickly, and later regret when they don't have the reserves left they'd need to get through harder times.
There are people who value long term stability too highly, only to recognize at the end that they've failed to live a life.
And there are even people who "overspend" or "overspare" like crazy but are fine with the consequences.
Reinforcing any part of the equation certainly does something, but without the whole picture, we can't know whether it's actually good or bad.

@GfEW3vHy Yeah, it's only a potential benefit, like I said. It is OPs money, so in my mind they can also have part in deciding what kind of influences to give, so I feel it is worth mentioning the possible effect of particular solutions. A trust often has even greater limitations on spending schedule.

This is called a trust - you can set it up such that the assets inside it can only be transferred to your sister and only after twenty years have passed. She would be the beneficiary - the person who will eventually benefit from the trust, but does not necessarily have control over what it does.
There are lots of details involved with setting up a trust that will protect the contents from personal lawsuits against you as the grantor or from your sister trying to access it immaturely - all of this is best done by a financial advisor or tax attorney who make their whole careers out of helping people like you do exactly this.

What does this add that couldn't have been a comment/edit on @Hilmar's answer?

It's probably worth mentioning stock options as a way of getting exposure to stock appreciation without ownership. But they're not suitable for such a long timeframe.
